# Airflow Oracle connection: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'backend'

Tags: airflow-connections

I have a question about Ariflow oracle connection. I tried a lot but couldn't find a solution, I need your help. I am using Airflow 2.5.1 version on Ubuntu machine, I have installed oracle provider etc. everything is available in the db network, but when connecting, I get this error:**init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'backend'

I made connection configurat[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9juh.png)ions but I'm getting errors.

airflow connections add 'oracle_con' 
--conn-json '{
"conn_type": "Oracle",
"login": "***",
"password": "****",
"host": "192.****",
"port": 1521,
"schema": "DWH",
"extra": {
"sid": "X***",
"dsn": "192.****"
}
}'

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).